# Удаление слов в строке которые превышают лимит в кол-во символов в слвое

Tags: python, строки

Совсем новичок в программировании и Python, поэтому по прошу вас более ясно и если можно с подробностями поделиться вашим решением :D

Задача:
 Исключать слова в строке которые превышают лимит в 4 (или любое кол-во) символов в слове. К примеру в строке с предложением: 'How can I help you?' он исключал слова how, can, i, you.

Хочу реализовать это через ввод пользователя через input, то есть сначала пользователь в консоли вводит предложение, а в конце программа уберет слова которые превышают лимит символов в слове.

Заранее спасибо за ваше решение!

Comment: возможно, вы имели ввиду удалить слова, в которых недостаточно символов ?

Comment: 1. Для начала, поделитесь своим кодом. 2. Так исключать слова, превышающие лимит, или наоборот, оставлять только их? Перечитайте свое условие - сами запутаетесь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# Ввод сообщения
message = input("Write your message: ")

# Делим строку на список слов
words = message.split(' ')

# Фильтруем слова по требованиям
filtred = list()

for word in words:
    # Игнорируем слова чья длина меньше 4 символов
    if len(word) < 4:
        continue

    # Прочие условия пишем здесь...

    # Остальные добовляем в список
    filtred.append(word)

# Выводим новою строку
newmessage = ' '.join(filtred)
print(newmessage)
```

Или тоже самое в две строки

```py
inp = input("Write your message: ")
out = ' '.join([word for word in message.split(' ') if len(word) >= 4])

print(out)
```